# Require Oracle query join with two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a oracle sql query by joining the below queries.

```
    <b>Table First</b>

+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+----------+
|              ID                   |FColumn1    |FColumn2 |FColumn3 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|              1                    | f1         |    f2   |    f3   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+----------+    

        <b>Table Second</b>  
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|           Ref                     |SColumn1    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|              1                    | Data1      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|              1                    | Data2      |    
+-----------------------------------+------------+
|              1                    | Data3      |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Sql to get the below output. any help is much appreciated. I have other columns too in both tables, for simple explanation. I have only shown what is required for me.

```
**Output table**

+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+----------+
|           ID                      |FColumn1    |FColumn2 |FColumn3 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|              1                    | Data1      |  Data2  |  Data3  |
+-----------------------------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add some more sample data to make the question clearer.

Comment: Added more data

Answer (score 0):

If you want the expected result as per the sample data provided in the question then it is quite simple.

```
SELECT F.ID, MIN(S.SCOLUMN1) AS FCOLUMN1, MAX(S.SCOLUMN1) AS FCOLUMN2
  FROM FIRST_TABLE F JOIN SECOND_TABLE S
    ON F.ID = S.REF
GROUP BY F.ID
```

Comment: Hi Tejash, my second table was wrong in my early query. I have corrected it. Please suggest me the query.

Comment: It is not limited to two column, it can any.

Comment: Oracle does not support dynamic number of columns in the static SQL. You must go for a dynamic query then.